# Error Returning PK id on UPSERT in PostgreSQL preventing ON CONFLICT from running

Tags: database, postgresql, insert

I need to return the ID of an existing record `songid` (PK serial) when the insert conflicts one of the values of `sc_link, yt_link, spot_link`.

`sc_link, yt_link, spot_link` all have unique constraints placed on them.

When I run this query

```
INSERT INTO songs (created, lat, lng, mood, genre, format, cxc_views, sc_link, yt_link, spot_link, soundcloud_id_author, yt_channel_id_author)   
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '51.06901665960392', '-129.02343750000003', 'joyful', 'reggaeton', '', '0', NULL, 'vYeenwUBjRg', NULL, NULL, 'UCG94rpZEA7WG1eN_UC8GsDA')   
ON CONFLICT (sc_link, yt_link, spot_link)
DO UPDATE SET title=EXCLUDED.title
RETURNING songid;
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "yt_unique"
DETAIL:  Key (yt_link)=(vYeenwUBjRg) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

Which would be fine (I know there is a dupe), except I need to get the `songid` back so I can show the user the song is already on the app.

Also, the `ON CONFLICT` is not even running, as I get the same error when I remove the last three lines.

Why is the `ON CONFLICT`and below not running? The other SO answers showed this UPSERT solution working well.

I am new to PostgreSQL, using 11.4, porting the application from MySQL. Thanks!!

Comment: Apparently you have another unique constraint on **only** the column `yt_link` which causes that error. You probably want `on conflict (yt_link)` instead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have unique constraints on all three, ``yt_link, sc_link, and spot_link`` The idea is that if any are not unique the insert will become and update. The problem, however, was that the ON CONFLICT wasn't even called, as the error came before "Also, the ON CONFLICT is not even running, as I get the same error when I remove the last three lines."

Comment: The error message clearly says you have (another) unique constraint on **only** the column `yt_link`. Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete `create table` statement including all `create index` statements